# SSRS Action to Change Value of Variable

Tags: variables, filter, parameters, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using SSRS 2008 R2 to create a report which is a directory of contacts so people can find this easily.  I've got the report working but the list is huge so I want to add dynamic filters by setting text boxes up that if anyone clicks on it, the results will be filtered.

I've set up a test report with a text box with an action to re-open the report but with the parameter set to ="A" to only pull back contacts beginning with the letter A.  However, when I click this, I get the following error:

> The report parameter 'Initial' is read-only and cannot be modified.
>   (rsReadOnlyReportParameter)

As an alternative, I've thought about adding a variable to the report and basing the parameter on this value.  The only thing is that, although there's plenty out there showing how to change the value of a variable, I cannot seem to find a way to set up an action to change one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

No worries everyone - I've found the answer.  The first solution works but the parameter has to be set to hidden, not internal as I had set it up.